# Замедляет ли php framework скорость работы кода?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, замедляют ли фреймворки скорость работы кода? Как будет код работать быстрее - на чистом php или на фреймворке? И защищает ли фреймворк от sql инъекции и от таких вещей? Безопасен или нет?

Comment: Вообще все зависит от фреймворка. А так же ваших навыков написания быстрого кода. В принципе большинство универсальных решений работают медленнее, чем код точно заточенный под задачу. А фреймворки стараются делать именно универсальными. С другой стороны вы можете написать на чистом php код, который будет работать медленнее, чем на хорошо сделанном фремворке

Comment: Да - замедляет. На чистом !!!функциональном!!! php будет работать быстрее (ооп в принципе работает медленней), фреймворк не защищает от sql-инъекций, защищают библиотеки типа ActiveRecord и здравый смысл, безопасность зависит от фреймворка. Хотя про скорость работы кода я бы думал в последнюю очередь - разница как правило незначительная, большую часть времени съедает обмен данными

Comment: Да, в любом случае будет работать медленнее, чем на чистом `php`. Так-как, тоны классов и зависимостей. Я не сижу на фреймворках, так-как очень много лишнего, что просто может не использоваться, а будет потреблять ресурсы. Советую изучить язык и писать именно то, что нужно вам, а с фреймворком еще нужно разобраться, по мимо самого языка. Вы можете взять фреймворк в качестве изучения или заимствования того или иного функционала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современные и поддерживаемые фреймворки безопасны (особенно если своевременно их обновлять).

Защита от SQL-инъекций есть, НО нужно уметь пользоваться этой защитой (читайте документацию о фреймворке), в противном случае даже используя фреймворк, неопытный программист может допустить уязвимости. Бонусом: фреймворк предоставляет плюшки по защите не только от SQL-инъекций.

Замедляет? Да, замедляет, чистый "Hello World" сгенерируется быстрее, но стоит понимать, что чаще всего мы тут говорим о копейках (и обычный пользователь даже не заметит разницы). Но стоит понимать что фреймворк взамен предлагает вам экономить кучу своего времени, куча полезных функций, уже реализована структура и архитектура, все готово, программисту остается только сконцентрироваться на задаче.

Расписывать все преимущества фреймворков - очень длинно и кто-то это сможет сделать лучше меня. Но вкратце: все нормальные проекты используют фреймворки. Просто почитайте документацию любого фреймворка, посмотрите уроки и сразу поймете на сколько фреймы хороши.

Про время работы стоит добавить то, что в 99% случаев генерация страницы зависит не от фреймворка а от того кода, который вы напишете сами.